# Chrome - Batch add microphone permissions to multiple sites

Tags: google-chrome, audio, permissions, administrator, microphone

I am working on a Chrome extension that allows user input via microphone. There is a finite but somewhat large list of sites that the extension is supposed to be used on.

Right now, the user must accept microphone access on every new page that the extension operates on. Is there a way either with some scripting, or via an IT/administration approach to add a list of approved sites at once?

I am not asking how to by-pass the Chrome permission dialog, but rather how to set it up so that during the installation of the extension (or after installation), many sites can be approved at once? **Is there a "batch add" feature in Chrome? Is there a workaround?** I'm trying to avoid having the user confronted with the permission dialog dozens of times as they use a set of websites.

Comment: Google publishes GPO templates for their products. Have you looked into those? https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for replying. 

I have looked at the group policy stuff, and I eventually reached this page: 
https://getadmx.com/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::AudioCaptureAllowed

The issue is this is a group policy approach to either broadly allow the microphone, or to have it ask the user on a per-site basis. There doesn't appear to be anything more finely grained than "allow all/ask/block all". The group policy approach would be the perfect solution if it would also let me specify a whitelist of pages for the microphone.

Comment: @NorbertKlang there are deep permissions assignments that you can use. There are samples in the Google chrome templates. I just had to do this for a project and was able to assignments specific permissions for domains via registry values. (We don't have power or internet right now so I can't share the code)

Comment: @shawn Thank you, after using the phrase 'deep permissions' in my search I was able to find this link: 

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionSettings

And the relevant setting appears under 'AudioCaptureAllowedUrls'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented below, the user @shawn used the phrase 'deep permissions', which I used to find the link here:

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionSettings

The setting I was looking for appears under the heading:

***AudioCaptureAllowedUrls***